# How to stop XMLRPC attacks on a Wordpress install

Tags: php, wordpress, security, nginx, xml-rpc

I am the latest victim getting hit hard by the XMLRPC.php attacks. I have tried options from tons of blogs but cant seem to get my site to stay alive for more than a couple of hours. I have tried:

1 - Edit my nginx config file to add

```
#Block XMLRPC
location ~* ^/xmlrpc.php$ {
return 403;
}
```

This seemed to work somewhat as now my nginx access log shows more 403 errors when trying to access xmlrpc.php. This did not stop the attacks from happening and the site is still extremely slow.

2 - I dont want to use any more plugins from WP.

3 - I have not tried to disable all XMLRPC in the functions, this is the next step.

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

4 - The only thing that has worked for me to keep my site running fast is something that not one of the 20 blog posts on this subject mentioned, renaming the file. I renamed xmlrpc.php to xmlrpc_old.php and my site instantly was responsive. If disabling XML-RPC through functions or config files, can't we just rename or delete that file? What is the difference?

5 - What can I implement to stop the attacks from happening? My server(LEMP) runs HAProxy and Cloudflare free.

Thanks

Comment: It's best to just put the entire WP install in a non-root folder these days. Check out the Bedrock version of WP in the roots.io stack - they do a lot of the little things you should be doing for your WP install for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option the iThemes Security plugin to disable it. https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

I know you say you don't want more plugins, but this plugin is well worth the additional overhead. It will save you time and go a long ways to improve the security of your WordPress site. I'm very much against bloat, but I install this on almost all WordPress sites I build.